# redefining indexpagestyle: headings with alternating part and chapter title

Tags: sectioning, indexing

I have a problem defining the headings in the index.
In the main text, part- and chapter-titles appear (alternating) in the headings. For the preamble (chapter "Vorwort"), I redefined this behavior for just the chapter titles appearing. This is realized by adding

```
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\lehead*{\pagemark}
\rohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\upshape}
```

At the beginning of the "content" parts and chapters, this is set to:

```
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\lehead*{\pagemark}
\rohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\upshape}
```

Works perfectly, except for the index. **The index is located in the part "Anhang", so instead of appearing "Register" on every index page, there should be "Anhang" and "Register" alternating.**
The first page of the index is configured by using

```
\newpairofpagestyles{IndexStyle}{%
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}
}
\renewcommand*{\indexpagestyle}{IndexStyle}
```

So I guess for the behavior I need to have, the indexpagestyle has to be edited in another/additional way, but I have no glue how to get that working...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=10pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[papersize={210mm,297mm},text={113mm,180mm},inner=77mm,outer=20mm,top=34mm,bottom=83mm]{geometry}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill} 
\KOMAoptions{headings=optiontohead}
\usepackage[indentunit=0.5em]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{acronym}
\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textrm{\textrm{\acsfont{#1}}}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\lehead*{\pagemark}
\rohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\upshape}

\newpairofpagestyles{IndexStyle}{%
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}
}
\renewcommand*{\indexpagestyle}{IndexStyle}

\begin{document}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\lehead*{\pagemark}
\rohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\upshape}

\addchap[tocentry={}]{Vorwort}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext

\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\lehead*{\pagemark}
\rohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\upshape}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
\tableofcontents

\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\lehead*{\pagemark}
\rohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\upshape}

\part{Part I:lksdjklsdjfjkls...}
\chapter{first chapter}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext

\blindtext\index{Aaronsen, John} Other names to be indexed are Mike Arjonen\index{Arjonen, Mike} and Jim Azzz\index{Azzz, Jim}. For B, there are John Baily\index{Baily, John} and Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim}a\index{Bronson, Jim2} b\index{Bronson, Jim3} c\index{Bronson, Jim4}n\index{Bronson, Jim5}k\index{Bronson, Jim6}b\index{Bronson, Jim7}n\index{Bronson, Jim8}b\index{Bronson, Jim9}b\index{Bronson, Jim10}.
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim11}a\index{Bronson, Jim12} b\index{Bronson, Jim13} c\index{Bronson, Jim14}n\index{Bronson, Jim15}k\index{Bronson, Jim16}b\index{Bronson, Jim17}n\index{Bronson, Jim18}b\index{Bronson, Jim19}b\index{Bronson, Jim20}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim21}a\index{Bronson, Jim22} b\index{Bronson, Jim23} c\index{Bronson, Jim24}n\index{Bronson, Jim25}k\index{Bronson, Jim26}b\index{Bronson, Jim27}n\index{Bronson, Jim28}b\index{Bronson, Jim29}b\index{Bronson, Jim30}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim31}a\index{Bronson, Jim32} b\index{Bronson, Jim33} c\index{Bronson, Jim34}n\index{Bronson, Jim13}k\index{Bronson, Jim36}b\index{Bronson, Jim37}n\index{Bronson, Jim38}b\index{Bronson, Jim39}b\index{Bronson, Jim40}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim41}a\index{Bronson, Jim42} b\index{Bronson, Jim43} c\index{Bronson, Jim44}n\index{Bronson, Jim45}k\index{Bronson, Jim46}b\index{Bronson, Jim47}n\index{Bronson, Jim48}b\index{Bronson, Jim49}b\index{Bronson, Jim50}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim51}a\index{Bronson, Jim52} b\index{Bronson, Jim53} c\index{Bronson, Jim54}n\index{Bronson, Jim55}k\index{Bronson, Jim56}b\index{Bronson, Jim57}n\index{Bronson, Jim58}b\index{Bronson, Jim59}b\index{Bronson, Jim60}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim61}a\index{Bronson, Jim62} b\index{Bronson, Jim63} c\index{Bronson, Jim64}n\index{Bronson, Jim65}k\index{Bronson, Jim66}b\index{Bronson, Jim67}n\index{Bronson, Jim68}b\index{Bronson, Jim69}b\index{Bronson, Jim70}b\index{Cronson, Jim}b\index{Dronson, Jim}b\index{eronson, Jim}b\index{Fronson, Jim70}b\index{Gronson, Jim70}b\index{Hronson, Jim70}b\index{Ironson, Jim70}b\index{Jronson, Jim70}b\index{Kronson, Jim}\index{Lronson, Jim}\index{Mronson, Jim}\index{Nronson, Jim}\index{Oronson, Jim}\index{Pronson, Jim}\index{Qronson, Jim}\index{Rronson, Jim}\index{Sronson, Jim}\index{Tronson, Jim}\index{Uronson, Jim}\index{Vronson, Jim}\index{Wronson, Jim}\index{Xronson, Jim}\index{Yronson, Jim}\index{Zronson, Jim}\index{Zronson, Jim2}\index{Zronson, Jim3}\index{Zronson, Jim4}\index{Zronson, Jim5}\index{Zronson, Jim6}\index{Zronson, Jim7}\index{Zronson, Jim8}

\part{Anhang}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Register}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Register}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

register.ist:

```
% sty.file for mkidx32.exe - redefines:
quote '+'
%headings_flag 0
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\textbf "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak%\n \\indexspace\\nopagebreak%"
delim_0 ": "
delim_1 ": "
delim_2 ": "
%delim_r "~--~"
delim_r "-"
%delim_0 "\\dotfill "
%delim_1 "\\dotfill "
%delim_2 "\\dotfill "
%delim_r "~--~"
suffix_2p "\\,f."
suffix_3p "\\,ff."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set `\chead` and `\ohead*` in the document. I think that an additional pagestyle `IndexStyle` is not needed. Maybe you want

```
\renewcommand{\indexpagestyle}{empty}
```

to get the same pagestyle for the first index page as for part and chapter pages in your document.

For the index `\@mkdouble{\MakeMarkcase{\indexname}}` (KOMA-Script class) or `\@mkboth{\MakeMarkcase{\indexname}}{\MakeMarkcase{\indexname}}` (package `idxlayout`) is used. So for the index `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` are set to  the `\indexname` if option `automark` is set. Note that `\automark` sets this option too.

To change this behaviour you can switch to `manualmark` (`\manualmark` or `\KOMAoptions{manualmark}`)  before `\printindex`:

```
{
  \cleardoublepage
  \manualmark
  \markright{MakeMarkcase{\indexname}}%
  \printindex
}
```

For the TOC entry of the index KOMA-Script option `index=totoc` should be used.

Example without the unrelated packages and settings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=10pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% <- changed
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[inner=77mm,outer=20mm,top=34mm,bottom=83mm]{geometry}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill} 
\KOMAoptions{headings=optiontohead}

\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\renewcommand*{\indexpagestyle}{empty}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\upshape}

\KOMAoptions{index=totoc}% <- added: TOC entry for index
\usepackage[indentunit=0.5em]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\indexname}{Register}% <- added (changed and moved to preamble)
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhalt}% <- added (changed and moved to preamble)


\begin{document}

{
  \automark[chapter]{chapter}
  \addchap[tocentry={}]{Vorwort}
  \Blindtext[25]
}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}
\Blinddocument
\blindtext\index{Aaronsen, John} Other names to be indexed are Mike Arjonen\index{Arjonen, Mike} and Jim Azzz\index{Azzz, Jim}. For B, there are John Baily\index{Baily, John} and Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim}a\index{Bronson, Jim2} b\index{Bronson, Jim3} c\index{Bronson, Jim4}n\index{Bronson, Jim5}k\index{Bronson, Jim6}b\index{Bronson, Jim7}n\index{Bronson, Jim8}b\index{Bronson, Jim9}b\index{Bronson, Jim10}.
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim11}a\index{Bronson, Jim12} b\index{Bronson, Jim13} c\index{Bronson, Jim14}n\index{Bronson, Jim15}k\index{Bronson, Jim16}b\index{Bronson, Jim17}n\index{Bronson, Jim18}b\index{Bronson, Jim19}b\index{Bronson, Jim20}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim21}a\index{Bronson, Jim22} b\index{Bronson, Jim23} c\index{Bronson, Jim24}n\index{Bronson, Jim25}k\index{Bronson, Jim26}b\index{Bronson, Jim27}n\index{Bronson, Jim28}b\index{Bronson, Jim29}b\index{Bronson, Jim30}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim31}a\index{Bronson, Jim32} b\index{Bronson, Jim33} c\index{Bronson, Jim34}n\index{Bronson, Jim13}k\index{Bronson, Jim36}b\index{Bronson, Jim37}n\index{Bronson, Jim38}b\index{Bronson, Jim39}b\index{Bronson, Jim40}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim41}a\index{Bronson, Jim42} b\index{Bronson, Jim43} c\index{Bronson, Jim44}n\index{Bronson, Jim45}k\index{Bronson, Jim46}b\index{Bronson, Jim47}n\index{Bronson, Jim48}b\index{Bronson, Jim49}b\index{Bronson, Jim50}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim51}a\index{Bronson, Jim52} b\index{Bronson, Jim53} c\index{Bronson, Jim54}n\index{Bronson, Jim55}k\index{Bronson, Jim56}b\index{Bronson, Jim57}n\index{Bronson, Jim58}b\index{Bronson, Jim59}b\index{Bronson, Jim60}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim61}a\index{Bronson, Jim62} b\index{Bronson, Jim63} c\index{Bronson, Jim64}n\index{Bronson, Jim65}k\index{Bronson, Jim66}b\index{Bronson, Jim67}n\index{Bronson, Jim68}b\index{Bronson, Jim69}b\index{Bronson, Jim70}b\index{Cronson, Jim}b\index{Dronson, Jim}b\index{eronson, Jim}b\index{Fronson, Jim70}b\index{Gronson, Jim70}b\index{Hronson, Jim70}b\index{Ironson, Jim70}b\index{Jronson, Jim70}b\index{Kronson, Jim}\index{Lronson, Jim}\index{Mronson, Jim}\index{Nronson, Jim}\index{Oronson, Jim}\index{Pronson, Jim}\index{Qronson, Jim}\index{Rronson, Jim}\index{Sronson, Jim}\index{Tronson, Jim}\index{Uronson, Jim}\index{Vronson, Jim}\index{Wronson, Jim}\index{Xronson, Jim}\index{Yronson, Jim}\index{Zronson, Jim}\index{Zronson, Jim2}\index{Zronson, Jim3}\index{Zronson, Jim4}\index{Zronson, Jim5}\index{Zronson, Jim6}\index{Zronson, Jim7}\index{Zronson, Jim8}


\part{Anhang}
{
  \cleardoublepage
  \manualmark
  \markright{\indexname}%
  \printindex
}

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can patch `\printindex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=10pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% <- changed
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[inner=77mm,outer=20mm,top=34mm,bottom=83mm]{geometry}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill} 
\KOMAoptions{headings=optiontohead}

\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\renewcommand*{\indexpagestyle}{empty}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize\upshape}

\KOMAoptions{index=totoc}% <- added: TOC entry for index
\usepackage[indentunit=0.5em]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
% patch for \printindex:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\printindex{\cleardoubleoddpage\manualmark\markright{\MakeMarkcase{\indexname}}}
  {}{\piIPatchFaled}
\xapptocmd\printindex{\automark[chapter]{part}}
  {}{\piIIPatchFailed}

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\indexname}{Register}% <- added (changed and moved to preamble)
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhalt}% <- added (changed and moved to preamble)


\begin{document}

{
  \automark[chapter]{chapter}
  \addchap[tocentry={}]{Vorwort}
  \Blindtext[25]
}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}
\Blinddocument
\blindtext\index{Aaronsen, John} Other names to be indexed are Mike Arjonen\index{Arjonen, Mike} and Jim Azzz\index{Azzz, Jim}. For B, there are John Baily\index{Baily, John} and Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim}a\index{Bronson, Jim2} b\index{Bronson, Jim3} c\index{Bronson, Jim4}n\index{Bronson, Jim5}k\index{Bronson, Jim6}b\index{Bronson, Jim7}n\index{Bronson, Jim8}b\index{Bronson, Jim9}b\index{Bronson, Jim10}.
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim11}a\index{Bronson, Jim12} b\index{Bronson, Jim13} c\index{Bronson, Jim14}n\index{Bronson, Jim15}k\index{Bronson, Jim16}b\index{Bronson, Jim17}n\index{Bronson, Jim18}b\index{Bronson, Jim19}b\index{Bronson, Jim20}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim21}a\index{Bronson, Jim22} b\index{Bronson, Jim23} c\index{Bronson, Jim24}n\index{Bronson, Jim25}k\index{Bronson, Jim26}b\index{Bronson, Jim27}n\index{Bronson, Jim28}b\index{Bronson, Jim29}b\index{Bronson, Jim30}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim31}a\index{Bronson, Jim32} b\index{Bronson, Jim33} c\index{Bronson, Jim34}n\index{Bronson, Jim13}k\index{Bronson, Jim36}b\index{Bronson, Jim37}n\index{Bronson, Jim38}b\index{Bronson, Jim39}b\index{Bronson, Jim40}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim41}a\index{Bronson, Jim42} b\index{Bronson, Jim43} c\index{Bronson, Jim44}n\index{Bronson, Jim45}k\index{Bronson, Jim46}b\index{Bronson, Jim47}n\index{Bronson, Jim48}b\index{Bronson, Jim49}b\index{Bronson, Jim50}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim51}a\index{Bronson, Jim52} b\index{Bronson, Jim53} c\index{Bronson, Jim54}n\index{Bronson, Jim55}k\index{Bronson, Jim56}b\index{Bronson, Jim57}n\index{Bronson, Jim58}b\index{Bronson, Jim59}b\index{Bronson, Jim60}
\newpage
text Jim Bronson\index{Bronson, Jim61}a\index{Bronson, Jim62} b\index{Bronson, Jim63} c\index{Bronson, Jim64}n\index{Bronson, Jim65}k\index{Bronson, Jim66}b\index{Bronson, Jim67}n\index{Bronson, Jim68}b\index{Bronson, Jim69}b\index{Bronson, Jim70}b\index{Cronson, Jim}b\index{Dronson, Jim}b\index{eronson, Jim}b\index{Fronson, Jim70}b\index{Gronson, Jim70}b\index{Hronson, Jim70}b\index{Ironson, Jim70}b\index{Jronson, Jim70}b\index{Kronson, Jim}\index{Lronson, Jim}\index{Mronson, Jim}\index{Nronson, Jim}\index{Oronson, Jim}\index{Pronson, Jim}\index{Qronson, Jim}\index{Rronson, Jim}\index{Sronson, Jim}\index{Tronson, Jim}\index{Uronson, Jim}\index{Vronson, Jim}\index{Wronson, Jim}\index{Xronson, Jim}\index{Yronson, Jim}\index{Zronson, Jim}\index{Zronson, Jim2}\index{Zronson, Jim3}\index{Zronson, Jim4}\index{Zronson, Jim5}\index{Zronson, Jim6}\index{Zronson, Jim7}\index{Zronson, Jim8}


\part{Anhang}
\printindex
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these two solutions, both work perfect!